# Instagram API で緯度、経度から場所idを取得してその画像を取得する

Tags: instagram, webapi

```php
<?php
    $client_id      = 'my_client_id';
    $client_secret  = 'my_client_secret';
    $redirect_uri   = 'my_redirect_uri';

    //アクセストークンを取得し、JSONをオブジェクト形式に変換
    $obj = json_decode(@file_get_contents(
        "https://api.instagram.com/oauth/access_token",
        false,
        stream_context_create(
            array("http" => array(
                "method" => "POST",
                "content" => http_build_query(array(
                    "client_id" => $client_id,
                    "client_secret" => $client_secret,
                    "grant_type" => "authorization_code",
                    "redirect_uri" => $redirect_uri,
                    "code" => $_GET["code"],
                )),
            ))
        )
    ));

    $user_id = $obj->user->id;
    $user_name = $obj->user->username;
    $user_picture = $obj->user->profile_picture;
    $access_token = $obj->access_token;

    header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8");

    $params = array(
        "access_token" => $access_token,
        "lat" => "35.69691",
        "lng" => "139.793512",
    );

    $query = http_build_query($params);

    $request_url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search";
 
    $obj = json_decode(@file_get_contents("{$request_url}?{$query}"));
 
    foreach($obj->data as $item){
    //ID・名前・緯度・経度
        $id = $item->id;
        $name = $item->name;
        $latitude = $item->latitude;
        $longitude = $item->longitude;

        echo "{$name} (場所ID:{$id} / lat: {$latitude} long: {$longitude}" ;
    }
?>
```

ここまではサイトを見ながらできたいのですが、特定のid(ここでは両国国技館)を持つ画像一覧を取得したい場合はこの後どのような処理をすれば良いのでしょうか？
自力で以下のコードを付け足してみたのですがうまくいかず悩んでいます。

```php
$request_url2 = "https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/"

$obj = json_decode(@file_get_contents("{$request_url2}/{$id}/media/recent?access_token={$access_token}"));

//個々のメディア情報
foreach($obj->data as $item) {
    $text = $item->caption->text;
    $image_file = $item->images->standard_resolution->url;

    // 出力
    echo "{$text} : <img src=\"$image_file\">";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

https://embedsocial.jp/blog/instagram-api-changes-2020-2/

上記ページによると、旧Instagram APIが2020年6月29日が廃止。

また、"プライバシー保護のため画像に位置情報が含まれなくなる" とも書かれています。

画像が位置情報（緯度・経度）を持たなくなると、質問のようなアプリケーションに影響しそうに思われます。